# Namespace-respecting relative import in Python

Tags: python, import, relative-path

I have this folder structure:

```
package/
    __init__.py
    misc/
        __init__.py
        tools.py
    subpackage/
        __init__.py
        submodule.py
```

I am in `submodule.py`, and I would like to import `misc.tools`. I don't want to use absolute import to import `package.misc.tools`, because then my package would only work when it's on the PYTHONPATH. So I want to use relative imports. But then, I also want the imported name to be `misc.tools`, and not just `tools`.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What about...:

```
from .. import misc
from ..misc import tools as _

print misc.tools.__file__
```

This makes `misc.tools` available, as the `print` confirms, and with the right name and contents.

Inevitably, it *also* binds the same module to some barename -- I've chosen `_` as a typical "throw-away barename", but of course you can `del _` right after that, if you wish, and that won't affect `misc.tools`.

Also, any other attribute of `misc` set in its `__init__.py` (or peculiarly in `tools.py`) will be available, but then, if the barename `misc` itself is available (as it must be if compound name `misc.tools` is required), then it's inevitable that it will have all attributes it builds for itself (or that get externally built for it from other code that executes).

Comment: I stumbled upon this today and it still works. But i am curious as to why? Could someone explain what happens here?